# syntax error, unexpected '{' in php

Tags: php, syntax

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($users->confirmEmail(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']),mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['activation'])){
        header( 'Location: login.php?msg=3' ) ;
    } else {
        header( 'Location: activate.php?msg=1' ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seriously? How about using a decent editor and try again ..

Comment: You have used (,)in if statement, may be that is the error

Comment: Syntax highlighting / IDE, and proper spacing usually help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing closing `)` of `if`.

```
 ...mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['activation']))
                                                  ^
                                                 here
```

Your code should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
if($users->confirmEmail(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']),mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['activation']))){
    header( 'Location: login.php?msg=3' ) ;
} else {
    header( 'Location: activate.php?msg=1' ) ;
    }
}
```

I'd recommend to use some IDE that has syntax highlight. Also errors are very descriptive nowadays. unexpected `{` means that there should be something before it.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a closing parenthesis in your `if`:

```
if($users->confirmEmail(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']),mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['activation']))){
```

If we replace the mysql-functions with x, it is easy to see:

```
if ( $users->confirmEmail(x,x) {
```

Comment: Thanks You Solve my problem : )